# Using multiprocess for a class method with a big DB inside the class

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to improve the performance of my python code.
After Profiling I've discovered that I have a bottle-neck inside a certain class-function, because this function has a lot of regex functionality.

as this function is being called multiple times (independently) I was thinking that using Multiprocess will be a good idea (this function is CPU-bound and not IO-bound and that's why I didn't use multi-thread)

For that I used concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.

The problem is that now I've created a new bottle-neck. As this class has very big DB (I need all of it for each run), fork.py takes a lot of time.

Is there any solution for this?

I was thinking about removing the DB from the class, then :

1. dump this DB to pickle from the father process
2. load it from each son

It sounds reasonable but on the other hand, if the solution is so simple, why is the OS doesn't use this method to copy data between processes?

clarification about this idea or any other idea will be much appreciated.

thanks,
Avishay.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: Help us to help you by showing your code